# Storing reference to vue Component in Data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm working on a project that is made to look like pseudo- operating system GUI, which obviously involves setting up windows that can be dragged and re-arranged with different content inside of them. Currently my setup just involves keeping an array in the data of App.vue called 'windows' to store the relevant information. I'm looking to store a reference to, or an actual value of, the components that get slotted inside of the window, so I can iterate through all the windows and have them all rendered with their correct containers with v-for.

--------------- App.vue -------------

```html
<template>
<div id="app">
  <div id="os">
    <window :info="window" :key="'window_'+index" v-for="(window, index) in windows">
    <!-- ^ Iterate through all stored windows ^ -->
        <slot-component></slot-component>
        <!-- ^ Ideally this would be a variable from data ^ -->
     </window>
 </div>
</div>
</template>
```

```html
<script>
import Window from './components/Window/Window'
import SlotComponent from './components/Webpages/SlotComponent'
import SlotComponent2 from './components/Webpages/SlotComponent2'
import SlotComponent3 from './components/Webpages/SlotComponent3'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      windows:[
        {
          title:"Window Title",
          active: true,
          innerComponent: slot-component
          // ^ Name or reference of component ^
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  components:{
    window: Window,
    slot-component: SlotComponent,
    slot-component2: SlotComponent2,
    slot-component3: SlotComponent3
  }
}
</script>
```

--------------- Window.vue -------------

```html
<template>
<div class="window" :class="info.active ? 'active' : 'inactive'">
    <div class="content">
        <slot></slot>
        <!-- ^ The component passed from data ^ -->
    </div>
    <div class="taskbar"></div>
</div>
</template>
```

If there's a better method for keeping track of children components dynamically, for a GUI like this, I'd love to hear that too. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to look into using [dynamic components](https://alligator.io/vuejs/dynamic-components/). I'd also look into the `keep-alive` attribute you can use around dynamic components if you're going to switch between them often.

Comment: @NickG Thanks! I'll have a look!